# load and dismiss a page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, document-ready

I am a noob to both jquery and jquery mobile. What I am trying to achieve is on a click of a link, to load a page, then after some period, automatically return to the original page. I don't care if this is done via jquery mobile "pages", or by following a link to another html page. While reading the docs, it sounded to me that it was preferable to keep pages in separate docs, so that is the path I followed. Clicking the link loads the new page just fine. However, I have not been able to get the new page to return.

The original page, football.html, has this link:

```
<li><a href="touchdown.html">Touchdown</a></li>
```

In touchdown.html, I have the following bit of javascript.

```
var TOUCHDOWN = {};

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("readying touchdown");
    window.setTimeout(TOUCHDOWN.goBack, 5 * 1000);
});

TOUCHDOWN.goBack = function() {
    alert("timedOut()");
};
```

Actually, as you can see, I am not even calling window.load(), I am just looking for the alert, which never seems to happen. In fact, I never see the alert "readying touchdown".

My question is really two-fold. First, am I even going down the right path? Or, would using a multi-page template be better? Or something else?

Second, I came across discussion in the docs about pageinit and elsewhere about pageload. Should I be using these functions instead? I have yet to find any examples of actually using either. I understand things way better if I see an example. The docs seemed to make it sound as if $(document).ready would only be called once, on the first page. Is what I want $(document).pageinit (or pageload)? Would it be that simple?

I've googled but seem to be coming up empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First, am I even going down the right path? Or, would using a
>   multi-page template be better? Or something else?

Using multiple HTML files is perfectly fine

Second, please use:

```
  $('#yourPageId').live('pageshow',function(event){
      setTimeout(function() { 
        $.mobile.changePage("football.html");
      }, 5 * 1000);
  });
```

Include this script in both files!

Comment: This got me closer. I need to do much more reading. Interstingly, when I click the touchdown link on football.html, the touchdown.html page displays and returns as desired, the script in football being executed. Inserting the script into both files was probably meant to redirect to football when touchdown was loaded directly. That was the only time the script was triggered. However, it only changes the address in the address bar, but does not show football. A non-issue for me, though a curiosity.